# Connecting to dev magento soap api v1 with self-signed certificate - wrong version error

Tags: php, web-services, magento, soap, wsdl

I need to connect to Magento SOAP API v1 dev server, which is running over https using self-signed ssl certificate.

Given my soap api url is: https://my-store.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl

The traditional way of initiating a soap client like this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($soap_api_url);
```

This produces the following error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from
>   'https://my-store.com/index.php/api/soap/?wsdl'

I figured the error must be due to self-signed certificate, so I tried a different approach like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);

$client = new SoapClient(null, [
    'location' => $soap_api_url,
    'uri' => 'urn:Magento',
    'stream_context' => $context
]);
```

This no longer complains about not being able to load the WSDL, now returns this error:

> Wrong Version

I think the problem is with the `uri` in the connection option; any idea how to tell this code I want to connect to v1 of the magento soap api?

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it like this:

```
$context = stream_context_create([
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true
    ]
]);

$client = new SoapClient($soap_api_url, [
    'stream_context' => $context
]);
```